# how to get return status and data from Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm not familiar with Restangular, is there an easy way to get return status and return data from Restangular? I tried to get these two value from response but failed:

```
    svc.sendHello = function() {
        var test = {"input":{"name":"hello"}};
        var ret_code = -1;
        var ret_data = "";
        svc.base().all('connectionmgr:greeting').post(test).then(function(response) {
            ret_code = response["status"]; //get the return code
            ret_data = response["data"]; //get the return data
            console.log(response);
        });
        return [ret_code, ret_data];
    };
```

Any suggestions about this issue?

Comment: move `return` statement inside success callback..

Comment: @SunilBN Hi, how to judge whether current call is successful ?

Comment: `svc.base().all('connectionmgr:greeting').post(test).then(function() {
    //success
  }, function() {
    //failed
  });`